# Not in aggregate function or group by clause but summing column in a window function

Tags: t-sql, window-functions

I'm getting the following error when trying to run the code below however usedslots is in a sum function.

`Column '#temp.UsedSlots' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

```
SELECT AppointmentMethod AS Category
      ,MonthStart           AS EventDate
      ,UsedSlots
      ,CASE
           WHEN MonthStart
                BETWEEN '01-APR-2022' AND '31-MAR-2023' THEN '2022-2023'
           WHEN MonthStart
                BETWEEN '01-APR-2023' AND '31-MAR-2024' THEN '2023-2024'
       END                  AS ContractYear
INTO #temp
FROM [Reports].[Service].[Slots]
WHERE SlotType LIKE '%AMR%'
      AND AppointmentMethod IN ('Home Visit', 'Face-to-face', 'Group')
      AND MonthStart >= '01-APR-2022'



SELECT Category
      ,EventDate
      ,sum(UsedSlots) OVER (PARTITION BY ContractYear
                            ORDER BY eventdate
                            rows unbounded preceding
                           ) AS Numerator
      ,'351'                 AS Denominator
FROM #temp
GROUP BY contractyear
        ,Category
        ,EventDate
```

I expected to get a running total based of UsedSlots per Contract Year broken down by appointment type. If I add UsedSlots into the group by then it gives me incorrect numbers:

| Category | EventDate | Numerator | Denominator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Face-to-face | 2023-04-01 | 0 | 351 |
| Face-to-face | 2023-04-01 | 1 | 351 |
| Face-to-face | 2023-05-01 | 2 | 351 |
| Face-to-face | 2023-05-01 | 4 | 351 |
| Face-to-face | 2023-05-01 | 7 | 351 |
| Home Visit | 2023-05-01 | 7 | 351 |

What is should give me is:

| Category | EventDate | Numerator | Denominator |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Face-to-face | 2023-04-01 | 2 | 351 |
| Home Visit | 2023-05-01 | 0 | 351 |
| Face-to-face | 2023-05-01 | 22 | 351 |

Is this the correct way to go about what I want to do or is there a different way I should be doing it? Thanks.

Comment: Sum() *over()* is a window function, *not* an aggregate function. Your first port of call should be the documentation!

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY` in your latter query when you don't have any (non-windowed) aggregation?

Comment: Just to take on to the existing comments: Windowed aggregates are already grouped, it is not necessary to provide a `GROUP BY` to use them. There doesn't appear to be any non-windowed aggregation going on here - remove the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, when using window functions, you don't need to additionally group the whole query, so you want something like:

```
SELECT Category
      ,EventDate
      ,sum(UsedSlots) OVER (PARTITION BY ContractYear, Category, EventDate
                            ORDER BY eventdate
                            rows unbounded preceding
                           ) AS Numerator
      ,'351'                 AS Denominator
FROM #temp
```